# Analysing reversible processes

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

> A reversible process is a process in which the system is in *mechanical* and *Thermal* equilibrium with its surroundings.

Consider a simple thermodynamic system: a gas in a vessel, with a piston (free to move).A large no. of pebbles are kept on the piston, each pebble having a **very** small mass: as we remove pebbles, we decrease pressure by an infinitesimal amount, and thus the pressure is varied slowly.

We wish to carry out a reversible expansion.Initially, The pressures and temperatures of the system and the surroundings are equal.

- My (guess) for what happens in this process: Suppose we remove a single pebble: the pressure decreases infinitesimally, and the gas expands: This causes the Temperature and volume of the system to change slightly.(suppose the temperature decreases from $T$ to $T-\Delta(T)$).Since the surrounding Temperature is now higher, some heat flows into the system.

I had initially thought the some heat simply flows and decreases the temperature of the surroundings, (and increases the temperature of the system) to some value $T^{'}$, and then the situation becomes static. We then remove the subsequent pebbles,in a similar fashion.

**however**, this picture leaves me confused with how exactly can we carry out an **isothermal** reversible expansion: There doesn't seem to be any mechanism that enforces $T_{sys}=T_{surr}=T$ throughout the process.

- *is my picture correct*?
- If my picture is correct: How exactly can we carry out an isothermal, reversible expansion?

Comment: Please correct this: " some heat simply flows and decreases (and increases) the temperature" - do you mean decrease *or* increase? Also, hopefully my answer to your other question provides an answer here as well. If you assume the surroundings has infinitely large heat capacity, then it can transfer to or absorb heat from the system without a change in its temperature.

Comment: @BuckThorn corrected

Answer (score 1):

After you remove a pebble, the same thing will start out happening as in the adiabatic process, and the gas temperature will decrease slightly.  This would cause heat to flow from the reservoir to the gas, and ithe gas would re-equilibrate to the reservoir temperature again.  So the overall result of removing just the tiny pebble would be that the pressure would decrease a little and the temperature would end up the same.

Answer (score 0):

As already in the answer by above, the process occurs infinitesimally, slowly and is a reversible process. As it occurs slowing the conditions such as net temperature of the system remains constant i.e. at each step of the reaction the equilibrium is restored by taking heat from the surroundings, but an overall isothermal process will occur. Similarly, we can consider it to be an action of two forces, where the driving force which is the force exerted by the gas due to removing the pebbles one by one, and the weight of the pebbles which is opposing. In such a situation if the we can consider the whole system to be at equilibrium. And if the weight of the pebbles is increased even slighly by dx then the system reverts back to the initial equilibrium, just before the pebble having mass dx was extracted.